# how to get time on next week

Tags: php

I need to write this line in php but not getting any ideas how to write .

Contest will start on every sunday and will reset after one week.

Contest will start on every sunday and Ends in   `<?php echo "next sunday time";?>`

Required Output:

Contest will start on every sunday and Ends in   `next sunday date: next sunday start time
or 
Contest Ends in   " countdown timer to next week start time "

Comment: I am removing the database tags, because the question seems exclusively about php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                   // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60 secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
// or using strtotime():
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: hermandez .. thanks -- I also need to display end time of next week i.e. when sunday starts , it will be end time of this week and star time of next week.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
$upcomingSunday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday'));
if you need the next sunday from a certain date

$date = strtotime('2010-07-01');
$upcoimngSunday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday', $date));
```

and what do you mean when you say "will reset after one week." ?

Comment: i want to display this for weekly activity contest . it stats on sunday and resets every one week.